# How to get a source code from webside opened by window.open

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get source code from website by window.open()

My CODE is very simple:

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://localhost/test.php?test=7", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");

alert(myWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
```

And I don't know why alert is blank.
Can you help me ? 
Regards

Comment: Sounds like you need to do this via AJAX. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: `innerHTML` is not the same that source code, because `innerHTML` includes all modification performed programatically by the scripts (removed and added elements). You want to get source code or the DOM tree structure?

Comment: Have you got a pop-up blocker on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the javascript source code from a website that you opened with `window.open`, you could do something like this:

```
var myWindow = window.open(...);

myWindow.onload = function() {
    var scripts = myWindow.getElementsByTagName("script");
    // ... get the inner text of each script
}
```

However, this only works for inline scripts; for script references, you'd have to open those pages, too, and read their text. That, or you could probably send a GET request to them.

As for your alert is blank, it could be for one or both of two reasons that I think of:

- You're acting on myWindow too early. The window returned by `window.open` doesn't immediately have a ready DOM for you. So, you may have to wait for the window to load using `onload` or something like that, before you try to read the body HTML.
- The webpage you're visiting doesn't have any HTML on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://localhost/test.php?test=7", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");

myWindow.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
         alert(myWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML) 
    }, 2000);
}
```

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/JRqTy/606/

Comment: Why the `setTimeout`?

Comment: @SirPython To allow time for the other window to load the page. But your method with `onload` is better.